# Adding a file from my desktop to an android device

Tags: android, file, adb, push, desktop

I am trying to add an html file from my desktop to my android device, i connect the device to my laptop using an usb cable. My laptop can't have access to my device's files. I followed this link :
https://www.androidauthority.com/android-customization-transfer-files-adb-push-adb-pull-601015/
and tried to push a file to my device using adb. But I got an error : "remote couldn't create file: Read-only file system"

Do you have any solution for my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question and include all the commands you have executed to push the file to the phone.

Comment: I solved my problem and pushed the file to my device, where can i find it now?

Comment: That depends on the path you pushed it to. As I already wrote you should edit your question and include the commands you have executed.